# How to convert a string list to (object) list in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the dictionary below in which the values are string type:

```
data = {'object_1':"['abc']",
'object_2':"['def']",
"object_3": "['xyz']",
"object_4": "['abc']"}
```

I want to convert the values of the dictionary from a string type to a list type. I tried to use `literal_eval` and `eval()` but without any success to get pure python lists:

*Desired output:*

```
data = {'object_1':['abc'],
'object_2':['def'],
"object_3": ['xyz'],
"object_4": ['abc']}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Note, these aren't "string lists". These are *strings*. For some reason, which you should probably address, they are string representations of lists, which you want to convert to lists. The easiest way to do that is with `eval`/`ast.literal_eval` (but again, you should address whatever is *creating these strings*).

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to create your second block or are you trying to make the values of the dict to be `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: I am trying: for col in data.columns: data[col] = data[col].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)) My goal is to get lists like ['abc'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saving the pandas file with different separator saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert the dict values from a string `"['def']"` to a list containing a string `['def']`, right? If that is the case you can do it with regex logic.

```py
import re 

data = {'object_1':"['abc']",
'object_2':"['def']",
"object_3": "['xyz']",
"object_4": "['abc']"}

exclude_brackets_quotes = lambda args: (args[0], [re.sub("[\[\]']", "", args[1])])

converted_data = dict(map(exclude_brackets_quotes, data.items()))
converted_data
```

This outputs

```py
{'object_1': ['abc'],
 'object_2': ['def'],
 'object_3': ['xyz'],
 'object_4': ['abc']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ast.literal_eval` this way:

```
import ast

converted_data = {key: ast.literal_eval(value) for key, value in data.items()}
```

Another solution is to use `strip` like so:

```
converted_data = {key: [value.strip("[]'")] for key, value in data.items()}
```